# Problema de importação de select list para a db

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Bom estou com problema ao importar um select list para a db, eu configurei mas mesmo assim dá erro, não importa o item selecionado

segue os códigos:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CRUD - Cadastrar</title>     
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Cadastrar Usuário</h1>
        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {
            echo $_SESSION['msg'];
            unset($_SESSION['msg']);
        }
        ?>
        <form method="POST" action="processa.php">
            <label>Nome: </label>
            <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite o nome completo"><br><br>

            <label>E-mail: </label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Digite o seu melhor e-mail"><br><br>

            <label>Posição Principal </label>
            <select name="Posição">
                <option value="Atacante">Atacante</option>
                <option value="Meia">Meia</option>
                <option value="Volante">Volante</option>
                <option value="Zagueiro">Zagueiro</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>


    <?php
session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");

$nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //nome
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); //sobrenome
$Posição = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Posição', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //posição principal

//echo "Nome: $nome <br>";
//echo "E-mail: $email <br>";

$result_usuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email, principal_position, created) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', $Posição, NOW())";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);

if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:green;'>Usuário cadastrado com sucesso</p>";
    header("Location: index.php");
}else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:red;'>Usuário não foi cadastrado com sucesso</p>";
    header("Location: index.php");
}

    -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.4
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Tempo de geração: 13/11/2017 às 00:52
-- Versão do servidor: 5.7.14
-- Versão do PHP: 7.0.10

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Banco de dados: `comunikar`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura para tabela `usuarios`
--

CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(220) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(220) NOT NULL,
  `Posição` varchar(220) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Fazendo dump de dados para tabela `usuarios`
--

INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id`, `nome`, `email`, `created`, `Posição`,`modified`) VALUES
(1, 'Matheus', 'matheus@comunikar.com.br', `atacante`,'2017-11-12 22:35:47', NULL),
(2, 'matheus1', 'matheus1@comunikar.com.br', `atacante`,'2017-11-12 22:37:15', NULL),
(3, 'matheus2', 'matheus2@comunikar.com.br', `atacante`,'2017-11-12 22:39:14', NULL),
(4, 'matheus4', 'matheus4@comunikar.com.br', `atacante`,'2017-11-12 22:41:21', NULL),
(5, 'matheus5', 'matheus5@comunikar.com.br', `atacante`,'2017-11-12 22:42:49', NULL),
(6, 'matheus6', 'matheus6@comunikar.com.br', `atacante`,'2017-11-12 22:48:27', NULL);

--
-- Índices de tabelas apagadas
--

--
-- Índices de tabela `usuarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de tabelas apagadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de tabela `usuarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;

    <?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$dbname = "dados";

//Criar a conexao
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
```

Segue o erro ao importar db

```
      Comando SQL:


    --
    -- Fazendo dump de dados para tabela `usuarios`
    --

    INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id`, `nome`, `email`, `created`, `Posição`,`modified`) VALUES
    (1, 'Matheus', 'matheus@comunikar.com.br', `atacante`,'2017-11-12 22:35:47', NULL),
    (2, 'matheus1', 'matheus1@comunikar.com.br', `atacante`,'2017-11-12 22:37:15', NULL),
    (3, 'matheus2', 'matheus2@comunikar.com.br', `atacante`,'2017-11-12 22:39:14', NULL),
    (4, 'matheus4', 'matheus4@comunikar.com.br', `atacante`,'2017-11-12 22:41:21', NULL),
    (5, 'matheus5', 'matheus5@comunikar.com.br', `atacante`,'2017-11-12 22:42:49', NULL),
    (6, 'matheus6', 'matheus6@comunikar.com.br', `atacante`,'2017-11-12 22:48:27', NULL)
    Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

    #1054 - Coluna 'atacante' desconhecida em 'field lis

t'
```

Comment: No campo atacante você não esta inserindo aspas simples e sim outro caracter que é como se fosse o da coluna do banco de dados. troque o ' ` ` ' por ' '

Comment: @NicolasPereira você diz isso na db?

Comment: O jeito correto é: `(1, 'Matheus', 'matheus@comunikar.com.br', 'atacante','2017-11-12 22:35:47', NULL),`

Comment: testei aqui porém sem exito, acho que o meu problema está nas tags, na parte do ´CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(220) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(220) NOT NULL,
  `Posição` varchar(220) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;´

Comment: @NicolasPereira na parte de posição, não sei se varchar é o correto para uma select list